# How to detect GUI control property changed in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

1) I have for example a `UIButton` and I want to change the layout of the view when the `Hidden` property is changed by binding. How can I subscribe to some kind of `HiddenChanged` event?

2) Is there some better way to repaint the view layout? I'm trying to solve standard form layout and when some controls `Hidden` property is set to true by binding, then move rest of controls up. Now I have there empty line between controls.

Comment: probably this will help https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4508/key-value-observing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to handle this yourself (which in my opinion is never the best option) i would use AutoLayout. this is the standard for building dynamic and adaptable user interfaces for iOS.

You can find more information in the Xamarin Documentation - [Auto Layout with the Xamarin Designer for iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/)